# EOFException when running nutch on the hadoop

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I am running nutch2.3 on the hadoop2.5.2 and hbase 0.98.12 with gora 0.6, when doing the process of nutch generate, hadoop throw an eofexception. any suggestion is welcome.

> 2015-05-18 15:22:06,578 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1362)) -  map 100% reduce 0% 2015-05-18
>   15:22:13,697 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1362)) -  map 100% reduce 50% 2015-05-18
>   15:22:14,720 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1441)) - Task Id :
>   attempt_1431932258783_0006_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:229)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)    at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.avro.AvroSerialization$AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroSerialization.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:302)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:170)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
>
> 2015-05-18 15:22:21,901 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1441)) - Task Id :
>   attempt_1431932258783_0006_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:229)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)    at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.avro.AvroSerialization$AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroSerialization.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:302)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:170)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
>
> 2015-05-18 15:22:28,986 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:printTaskEvents(1441)) - Task Id :
>   attempt_1431932258783_0006_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED Error:
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:128)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readIndex(BinaryDecoder.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:229)
>     at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)    at
>   org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.avro.AvroSerialization$AvroDeserializer.deserialize(AvroSerialization.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:302)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:170)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
>
> 2015-05-18 15:22:37,078 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1362)) -  map 100% reduce 100% 2015-05-18
>   15:22:37,109 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1375)) - Job job_1431932258783_0006
>   failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed
>   task_1431932258783_0006_r_000001 Job failed as tasks failed.
>   failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1
>
> 2015-05-18 15:22:37,256 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job
>   (Job.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1380)) - Counters: 50    File System
>   Counters      FILE: Number of bytes read=22       FILE: Number of bytes
>   written=232081        FILE: Number of read operations=0       FILE: Number of
>   large read operations=0       FILE: Number of write operations=0      HDFS:
>   Number of bytes read=612      HDFS: Number of bytes written=0         HDFS:
>   Number of read operations=1       HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
>         HDFS: Number of write operations=0  Job Counters        Failed reduce
>   tasks=4       Launched map tasks=1        Launched reduce tasks=5         Rack-local
>   map tasks=1       Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots
>   (ms)=10399        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots
>   (ms)=23225        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=10399        Total time
>   spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=23225      Total vcore-seconds taken by
>   all map tasks=10399       Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce
>   tasks=23225       Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=10648576
>         Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=23782400
>     Map-Reduce Framework        Map input records=1         Map output records=1
>         Map output bytes=32         Map output materialized bytes=62        Input split
>   bytes=612         Combine input records=0         Combine output records=0
>         Reduce input groups=0       Reduce shuffle bytes=14         Reduce input
>   records=0         Reduce output records=0         Spilled Records=1       Shuffled
>   Maps =1       Failed Shuffles=0       Merged Map outputs=1        GC time elapsed
>   (ms)=175      CPU time spent (ms)=6860        Physical memory (bytes)
>   snapshot=628305920        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3198902272
>         Total committed heap usage (bytes)=481820672    Shuffle Errors
>         BAD_ID=0        CONNECTION=0        IO_ERROR=0      WRONG_LENGTH=0      WRONG_MAP=0
>         WRONG_REDUCE=0  File Input Format Counters          Bytes Read=0    File
>   Output Format Counters        Bytes Written=0 2015-05-18 15:22:37,266
>   ERROR [main] crawl.GeneratorJob (GeneratorJob.java:run(310)) -
>   GeneratorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed:
>   name=[t2]generate: 1431933684-12185, jobid=job_1431932258783_0006     at
>   org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:213)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.generate(GeneratorJob.java:241)
>     at org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:308)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.main(GeneratorJob.java:316)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
>
> Error running:   /usr/pro/nutch2.3/deploy/bin/nutch generate -D
>   mapred.reduce.tasks=2 -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx1000m -D
>   mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D
>   mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false -D
>   mapred.compress.map.output=true -topN 50000 -noNorm -noFilter -adddays
>   0 -crawlId t2 -batchId 1431933684-12185

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem with the same config. My problem is solved by adding

```
<property>
  <name>io.serializations</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization</value>
  <description>A list of serialization classes that can be used for
  obtaining serializers and deserializers.</description>
</property>
```

to the nutch-site.xml. Thanks to http://quabr.com/26180364/cant-run-nutch2-on-hadoop2-nutch-2-x-hadoop-2-4-0-hbase-0-94-18-gora-0-5

Comment: It works for me too, As I understand this configuration disable avro for serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the process may be your problem will be solved!!

Edit ivy.xml — ​ Be careful very very important step

```
<dependency org=”org.apache.gora” name=”gora-hbase” rev=”0.6.1′′ conf=”*->default” />
```

```
<dependency org=”org.apache.solr” name=”solr-solrj” rev=”4.1.0′′ conf=”*->default” />
```

add this line

```
<dependency org=”org.apache.hbase” name=”hbase-common” rev=”0.98.8-hadoop2′′
conf=”*->default” />
```

go to Stack/apache-nutch-2.3.1/conf
Edit gora.properties

```
gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore
```

Edit hbase.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<!–Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its built in zookeeper files.–>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Edit nutch-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>http.agent.name</name>
<value>NutchSpider</value>
</property><property>
<name>storage.data.store.class</name>
<value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
<description>Default class for storing data</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>plugin.includes</name>
<value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-op
ic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Clean the Build for Nutch
ant clean
Build the nutch
ant runtime